# gnu sort alphanumerically by one column, followed by numerically in next column?

Tags: linux, sorting, gnu

How can I sort a text file with GNU sort starting with alphanumeric sort by one column, followed by numerical sort in the next column?

I tried `sort -n -k1,2 file.txt`, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
cluster-7402-walk-0270  100     136     SP3     0.959707
cluster-7402-walk-0270  113     137     SP1     0.959707
cluster-7402-walk-0270  117     136     SP2     0.959707
cluster-7402-walk-0270  117     136     SP4     0.959707
cluster-7402-walk-0270  118     140     SMAD4   0.984412
cluster-7402-walk-0270  121     144     ARNT    0.991913
cluster-7402-walk-0270  121     146     AHR     0.991913
cluster-7402-walk-0270  13      24      GTF2A1  0.965496
cluster-7402-walk-0270  13      24      GTF2A2  0.965496
```

Comment: I misread the man page in exactly the same way, thinking the integers after '-k' specified each of the fields I wanted sorting by. As @Thor's answer shows, they actually come in pairs, specifying the start and stop position of a single range of fields, hence any modifiers such as 'n' for numeric sorts apply to all fields in that range. If you want to sort by different fields using different modifiers, you need two ranges, i.e. two '-k args.

Comment: See the description of '--key' in the info page: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#sort-invocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For alphanumeric sorting you need to use *version sort*. The sorting type should be specified for each field, e.g. to sort alphanumerically on first column and numerically on next column use:

```
sort -k 1,1V -k 2,2n file.txt
```

See `info sort` and search for *sort field specified* for more on this.

Comment: One might expect '-kN,N' for integer N, could be abbreviated as '-kN', but this doesn't seem to work. Turns out '-kN' actually means "from field N to the end of line"